# keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException (Permission denied) while calling from docker file

Tags: certificate, dockerfile, keytool

I'm trying to install a certificate in docker image using my docker file

```
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64

COPY app-module/src/main/resources/certificates/A.crt /etc/ssl/certs/
COPY app-module/src/main/resources/certificates/B.crt /etc/ssl/certs/

RUN $JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -import -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -file /etc/ssl/certs/A.crt -alias A
RUN $JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -import -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -file /etc/ssl/certs/B.crt -alias B
```

I get the error

```
keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts (Permission denied)
```

Other answers I found suggested running the above command in root/administrator mode. However, I'm running these commands in Dockerfile. How do I get past this error?

Comment: Did you ever find your answer? I've got same issue. This worked for past 6 months or so, now broken...

Comment: @ChrisBeck, yes I did. The user in docker is by default ROOT. However the recipe I was using (maintained by my organisation) to create the docker image overrode that. Since the user no longer was ROOT, it didn't have the permissions anymore to add the certificate.Check my answer below for how to get past that

Comment: @ChrisBeck, please also upvote the question and/or answer since you found it useful. Cheers!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The default user in docker is root. I believe it has been set to a user other than root by your organisation for security purposes. You need to change to user root and then change back to whatever user had been set by your organisation.

```
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64

COPY app-module/src/main/resources/certificates/A.crt /etc/ssl/certs/
COPY app-module/src/main/resources/certificates/B.crt /etc/ssl/certs/

#change to user root to install certificates
USER root
RUN $JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -import -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -file /etc/ssl/certs/A.crt -alias A
RUN $JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -import -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -file /etc/ssl/certs/B.crt -alias B

#change to user oldUser to comply with organisation standards
USER oldUser
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late but for anyone having this issue these days, it may be because of the way you enter inside docker container.
Instead of:

```
sudo docker exec -it DOCKER_ID bash
```

You need to add a flag to enter as root:

```
sudo docker exec -u root -it DOCKER_ID bash
```

This will do the trick.